# unorderable types: dict() > list() Error

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to write a insertion sort for a few dictionaries, but it always gives the unorderable types error. I don't really know what the problem is here, so any help would be great!

```
for key in range (1, len(allData)):
        cvalue = [key]
        position = key
        while position >0 and allData[position-1] > cvalue:
            allData[position] = allData[position-1]
            position = position-1
            allData[position] = cvalue
```

Comment: `allData[position-1]` is a dictionary and `cvalue` is a list; what were you expecting that comparison to do, exactly? Did you mean `cvalue = allData[key]`?

Comment: Are you confused because Python 2.x let you sort these and Python 3.x doesn't, or are you confused because you think there's an obvious rule that should be used to compare dicts and lists and want to know how to make Python use that rule (if so, what's the rule?), or are you confused because you didn't know you were comparing dicts and lists in your code?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to write an insertion sort? The builtin `sorted` function does a hybrid sort that will usually beat an insertion sort, especially because it does the looping in C rather than in Python, and of course it already works so it doesn't need to be debugged.

Comment: @abarnert thanks! It's for an assignment and we're not allowed to use the built in functions. If I can't compare dicts and lists is there any way I can achieve the same outcome from python 2.x?

Comment: If you want to be able to sort elements of different types, you have to decide how you want them to be compared. First, if you want to compare dicts at all, what's the rule for when one dict is before the other? (Remember that dicts do not have any inherent order to their keys.) Then, if you want to compare dicts to lists, how should that work? Should all lists come before all dicts, or after, or should they be handled as if they were `{val0: None, val1: None, …}`, or…? Whatever rules you come up with, you can code up—but you can't write code without knowing what you want it to do.

Comment: If what you want really is "whatever Python 2 used to do, even though it's not useful for any real-life use case anyone has ever had, which is why it no longer exists in Python 3", I can link the documentation on what Python 2 did. But I doubt that's what you want.